# Javascript getElementById can't see ASP server controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to get an old ASP classic project up and running as an ASP.NET webfroms solution and I'm having problems getting the javascript to connect to the ASP controls.  Here is the .aspx code:

```
<asp:TextBox id="groupOwner2" CssClass="textbox" Runat="server" Enabled="False" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

And the javascript that is supposed to manipulate it looks like this, and is trying to clear the text box:

```
function OnChange() {
// clear existing data

document.getElementById('<%=groupOwner2.ClientID%>').value = "";}
```

Originally, the the javascript control reference looked like this:

```
document.Form1.elements["groupOwner2"]
```

and that didn't work either (unsurprisingly).   I've tried a number of variations on these but nothing has worked and I just get "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference" when the script is triggered.  For the record, the script is being triggered by another control which is why the onChange() function is not mentioned in the textbox ASP code.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't build JavaScript with server-side code. Your HTML belongs in `.html` files, your CSS belongs in `.css` files, likewise your JS belongs in `.js` files. Use `[class]` attributes, and select based on class. ASP makes a mess of IDs.

Comment: @zzzzBov "Class" is not necessarily the best way to select elements. Take a look at why Facebook uses `data-sigil` attributes. http://www.phabricator.com/docs/javelin/article/Concepts_Sigils_and_Metadata.html

Comment: Have you verified the generated script matches the ID in the generated HTML?

Comment: Like Mike said, the place where I would begin would be verify matching ideas.  Next, since your error says value is undefined, figure out when exactly you are calling your function.  If you call a ClientID before it is being created, you will get the undefined message.

Comment: @BradM, you're right, and there are many ways of selecting DOM nodes, but it would be naive of me to think that a new user to [SO], who doesn't even understand why building JavaScript with server side code is a *terrible* idea, would fully understand the merits of using custom attribute-based selectors.

Comment: @MikeChristensen The ID in the generated HTML is MainContent_groupOwner2, and changing the call to that doesn't do it either.  Plus, I thought that the <% .ClientID%> tag would have allowed me to call the controls by the server ID's.

Comment: @zzzzBov The javascript is in its own .js file, and I probably would have done it all in c# if I was going from the ground up.  However, this was given to me with javascript dealing with all the controls and I figured it would be easier to get the javascript hooked up than to re-write everything in c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue, judging by your latest comments, is that the code:

```
document.getElementById('<%=groupOwner2.ClientID%>').value = "";
```

is contained in a `.js` file, which (by default) is not handled by the ASP.NET engine.  Even if it was, it would have no way to resolve the Client ID as it's a completely separate HTTP request.

**There are two solutions:**

1) Create a global variable in the `.ASPX` page, something like:

```
<script>
var GROUP_OWNER_ID = '<%=groupOwner2.ClientID%>';
</script>
```

Then, in your `.js` file you can do:

```
document.getElementById(GROUP_OWNER_ID).value = "";
```

2) Use a static ID on the web control:

```
<asp:TextBox id="groupOwner2" CssClass="textbox" Runat="server" Enabled="False" TextMode="SingleLine" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Note the `ClientIDMode` attribute.  This will cause the ID to *always* be `groupOwner2` no matter what.  You can then just use:

```
document.getElementById('groupOwner2').value = "";
```

Comment: To avoid js namespace pollution it's even better to use the javascript namespacing pattern in the .aspx page: _var YourAwsomeAppSpace = YourAwsomeAppSpace || {}; YourAwesomeAppSpace.GROUP_OWNER_ID = '<%=groupOwner2.ClientID%>';_

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing I needed to learn.  Thanks Mike!

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
'<%= Page.[yourpage].FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("groupOwner2").ClientID %>'
```

Comment: No dice.  Tried with my page defined and "ContentPlaceHolder1" both as is and with the actual ContentPlaceHolder ID, MainContent.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

use  ClientIDMode="Static" 
you can put on page directive or specifically on control you are using.

then below code works perfectly. 
document.getElementById('controlID');

then controlID remains same always. you do not need to use clientid.